# Kotlin extension on interface

Tags: android, kotlin

Let's say I have an `interface Base` and that we implement that interface in `class Base1 : Base`.

I would expect an extension function in the form

```
fun ArrayList<Base>.myFun()
```

to also work on `arrayListOf(Base1(), Base1()).myFun()`, but it doesn't. It requires the list to be of type `Base` instead of `Base1`.

Isn't this really strange? Or am I just missing something?

And, what are my options to write a function available on all subclasses of an interface?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to allow extension function to accept child implementation

```
interface Base
class Base1: Base

fun ArrayList<out Base>.myFun() = println(toString())

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    arrayListOf(Base1(), Base1()).myFun()

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I prefer this over the generic approach. Although `T` bound to `Base` was a good idea as well.

Comment: @Algar this is also a generic approach. Generics are not defined by the use of `T`

Comment: Great, thanks :). I've never though about that way but... Great to learn something new!!

Answer (score 3):

Lets say that you have:

```
interface Base
class Base1: Base
class Base2: Base
```

To have a fun for each class that extends your interface, you should create a class with a generic extension:

`fun <T : Base> ArrayList<T>.myFun() = arrayListOf<T>()`

In this case what you are doing is do an extension on any `ArrayList` which container class would be any class that extends from your `Base` interface. In the same way it will return an arraylist of that type.

In code this will look like:

```
fun myCode(){
    val array1 : ArrayList<Base1> = arrayListOf(Base1()).myFun()
    val array2 : ArrayList<Base2> = arrayListOf(Base2()).myFun()
}
```

You can read more about it in the official documentation, it has a lot of generic examples too: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
fun ArrayList<Base>.myFun()
```

is an extension only on `ArrayList<Base>`.

You can make the function generic to support any implementers of `Base`:

```
fun <T : Base> ArrayList<T>.myFunc() {}
```

Usage:

```
ArrayList<Base1>().myFunc()
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work with array list of any type:

```
fun <T> ArrayList<T>.myFun()
```

Comment: TS aims to restrict hierarchy. In example you provided `T` has to be bound to `Base`, eg `fun <T: Base> ArrayList<T>.myFunn() `